# Выбор СУБД под большой проект

Tags: база-данных

Какую лучше СУБД выбрать под разработку большого проекта?
Mongo DB с ее автоматическим привлекающим внимание тысяч программистов, как пчел на мед, шардингом и вообще современными возможностями?
MySQL и аналоги ..?
SQLite3? Но у нее есть лимиты памяти баз данных и шардинг никакого смысла в увеличении скорости не придаст.

Comment: А как тут состыкуются большой проект и sqlite? Автор что-то нехорошее мутит. Кхм, кхм.

Comment: Вы простите. Я понял уже, что SQLite3 не подойдет.

Comment: Mongo DB, как вы, надеюсь, знаете, использует для запросов свой специфичный язык( это, как SQL в MySQL, например, но только не SQL =) ), поэтому придется изучать этот специфичный язык, но зато про атаки типа SQL Injection можно вовсе забыть...но вместе с этим MongoDB несет в себе и другие уязвимости...

Comment: Знал. Но надо же когда-нибудь развиваться. Хотя, как я понял Вас, это не развитие, а скорее более удобная модель.

Comment: оракл

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала нужно определиться с каким типом БД вы будете работать. По собственному опыту могу сказать, что нельзя ответить на вопрос "что лучше: монго или sql". Нужно исходить из поставленной задачи.

Документо-ориентированные БД (mongo, couch) будет лучше если в системе вам часто приходится копировать записи с их зависимостями. Или, например, если не все записи имеют одинаковые поля.

Если же вам приходится обрабатывать массивы данных для подсчёта неких статистических данных (например, среднее состояние кассы всех компаний за N-ый период), то здесь к месту реляционный подход (mysql, postgresql).

Поэтому, чтобы сузить круг выбора БД, для начала выберите её тип исходя из поставленной вам задачи.

Comment: Правильный подход. Благодарю.

Comment: истина посередине. ) в больших проектах можно разделить данные на SQL и NoSQL базы.. к примеру. справочники, журналы и документы хорошо хранить в NoSQL, в то время как регистры и отчеты в SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Есть большая тройка: Oracle, MS SQL Server и IBM DB2. Все остальное это детские шалости, ну разве что MySQL и Postgres близки к этим гигантам.

Когда вы говорите **большой** проект, то видимо речь идет не столько о том, что много данных, но видимо и о том, что много серверов, много коннектов. По человечески умеют делать кластеризацию только указанные монстры, а всякая мелочь вроде MongoDB и проч. - не смешите. Ну запихнете вы туда 100 гигов (и то сомневаюсь), а дальше то что? Ну про SQLite вообще умолчу: ключевое слово здесь lite - то есть легкий, маленький. Хорошо, хоть не упомянули про Hypersonic SQL :)

Когда проект большой на первый план выходит не столько способность вмещать данные, столько возможность "держать" нагрузку, использование фич специализированных серверных процессоров, возможность кластеризации, бэкапа, репликации данных между инстансами. Ну и не забываем про поддержку. Какую вы поддержку получите с MongoDB и тем паче с SQLite? Форум полусумасшедших разработчиков-индусов?

В общем смотрите в сторону большой тройки. Я лично, предпочитаю Oracle.

**P.S.** Почитав про цели:

> Ну если говорить о базе жителей города
> и устройстве у них лк по мониторингу
> электричества, например.

мне становится страшновато за жителей города или за Чубайса, поскольку счета за электричество с SQLite'ом точно не будут оплачены...

Comment: 1. Спасибо за профессиональный совет.
2. И Вы туда же. Я лишь выясняю. Да что там говорить. Главное же, бросить камень в чужой огород из своего.

Comment: Да ладно, я уж шутя - не бери в голову...

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli или PDO, смотря какая связка.

В данный момент для большого проекта, я выбрал MySQLi + PHP + Jquery + Memcache

Comment: Опа. Спасибо. Получается, что MySQLi может быть объектно-ориентированным, но в то же время она реляционная. И может делиться на секции. Век живи - век учись.

Comment: @morfei, а для мелкого проекта вы бы, значит, Jquery не выбрали, как и весь JavaScript, да? Ну HTML еще для "большого проекта" осталось выбрать =)

Comment: Он, наверное, хотел сказать, передачи запросов и данных через AJAX, для снижения нагрузок.

Comment: @qsad, Ни Mysqli, ни PDO не являются СУБД- это обертки над api mysql. Будьте внимательнее.

Answer (score 0):

Никакого MySQL. Юзайте постгрес!)

Comment: С горизонтальным секционированием?

Comment: Хотя не суть. У него там это вообще встроено. Спасибо.

Comment: @nolka, на что полагаясь, вы это так однозначно заявили?

Comment: На то, что мы успели наесться говна с mysql в своем проекте, когда часть логики нужно было реализовать средствами СУБД

Comment: поддерживаю! postgres рулит! ) да начнется холивар! )

Answer (score 0):

[@qsad](/users/10299/qsad), что значит (количественные характеристики) **большой проект?**.

Во многих больших проектах (кластеры из несколько серверов   и систем хранения в SAN, терабайты дискового пространства) используют Oracle, DB2 или MS-SQL.

Кое с какими данными на эту тему можно ознакомится [здесь](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/default.asp)

Comment: Имелось в виду, что база данных может составить более 32ТБ, а хотелось использовать SQLite3. Вопрос отпал. Спасибо и Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать то, где у Вас больше всего опыта.
И на MySQL можно построить отличные решения. [Шардинги, репликации и партиционирование](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/05/06/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86/) там тоже есть.

Answer (score 0):

Холивары вокруг того какая СУБД самая-самая — весьма популярный в интернете вид спорта. Большинство ответов тут, увы, именно про это. Дабы не повышать напряжённость постараюсь вовсе не упоминать тут названия различных СУБД.

[[@qsad](/users/10299/qsad)](/users/10299/qsad), наблюдение за подобными холиварами едва-ли поможет вам разобраться в вопросе, скорее наоборот запутает. Так-же не стоит рассчитывать услышать тут правильный ответ на ваш вопрос. Дело в том что сделать правильный выбор тут можно только зная в подробностях что должна делать система, имея представление об имеющихся ресурсах (людских и материальных). И самое главное: разбираясь в предметной области. К сожалению вынужден констатировать что, судя по вашему вопросу, ваших знаний недостаточно для того что-бы задаваться правильными вопросами (а это наверное самое главное).

Если у вас есть время, мозги, желание и готовность долго изучать что-то не связанное напрямую с решением конкретной задачи — изучите получше эту тему. Базы данных и проектирование восоконагруженных и высокодоступных систем это вообще интересно.

Если «проект нужно сдавать уже вчера», или сама тема вам не интересна — наймите опытного DBA (Database administrator). Хоть я и не представляю как вы отличите адекватного DBA от чёрт-знает кого.

P.S. должен заметить что у меня есть некоторые соображения о том как-бы могла выглядеть подобная система. Но я не стану их озвучивать, учитывая что: во-первых мои соображения основываются на представлении о целевой системе сложившемся из обрывков информации предоставленных [[@qsad](/users/10299/qsad)](/users/10299/qsad) и гадании на кофейной гуще, во-вторых моего опыта и познаний очевидно недостаточно что-бы проектировать такие системы.

Answer (score -2):

Работаю с БД размером ~70 Гб, строк больше 300 млн., и это MySQL!
Проблем нет!

Comment: Поздравляю. Но не факт, что у других будет так же. Кроме размеров есть и другие параметры. Например частота обновления данных, добавления/удаления, время реакции и пр.

Comment: частота обновления данных, добавления/удаления каждую секунду...))

просто люди начитаются что вот какая-там MongoDB мега супер крутая, а им это не нужно! Достаточно старого доброго мускула (версию лучше последнюю кончено) и грамотно продуманную структуру БД, а также её конфиг.

P.S.
один из самых популярных сайтов в мире FB работает именно на MySQL!

Comment: @ARISTARH, да вы правы, что старого доброго мускула в основном хватает. Но вы не совсем корректны по поводу FB! Фейсбук использует MySQL и Cassandra. Ведь у каждой базы свои "фишки". А вообще если интересно что использует фейсбук, то почитайте http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/06/18/the-software-behind-facebook/

Comment: Да я в курсе, читал как-то на хакер ру http://www.xakep.ru/post/55510/